# 2nd story, walk under, completely brick deck

Tags: deck

Is it possible to have a 2nd story deck, fully made out of bricks (IE supports are made of brick, you walk/sit on top of bricks), that you can walk underneath and store stuff underneath? I can't recall ever seeing one and am wondering if there is a good reason.

Comment: What would the brick decking be supported with?  Bricks are small, and you need something long to span the area of the deck so you can get under it.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is how to span the gap.

Bricks and the mortar joining them are strong in compression but weak in tension. So you can't really build a thin flat deck out of them. You could build arches but it would seriously cut into the space under the deck and a lot of fill material would be needed to bring the top of the arches to a flat surface.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can build a walk out of bricks. The Romans first did it about 4,000 years ago, but it would take a substantial amount of space for the arches, etc.

We do it now using Rebar and grout inside a hollow space (void) built out of bricks. The bricks are constructed on wood forms and then rebar and grout are installed in the void. After it all sets up, the forms can be taken away and it’s self-supporting.

It’s very difficult and I’d recommend you hire a structural engineer (not a civil engineer) or an architect.

Comment: I wonder if you could just bricks with holes in and tubes containing threaded rod, to form a "post tensioned brick" deck a single brick thick.